# Only last member of a list gives a Rectangle Intersect xna

Tags: c#, xna

This is a similar problem to what I posted here: [Only last made member of a list is updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25632050/only-last-made-member-of-a-list-is-updating)

Again I have a list of Players (for multiplayer purposes) and a list of blocks(basically a texture with an assigned position and rectangle).

I have a function named `Collision Engine` which is *supposed* to detect collisions between each block in the list and the player.

here is the function I am using to attempt to detect if the player is intersecting with *any* block (in this case 500 randomly generated trees).

```
foreach (Blocks b in main.initializer.blocklist)
{
    foreach (Player p in main.initializer.playerlist)
    {

                if (p.Hitbox.Intersects(b.box))
                {
                    p.intersection = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    p.intersection = false;
                }

    }
}
```

At first I thought it just wasn't detecting collision at all, but then I noticed it *is* detecting collision, however it only detects it on the last placed block in the list (figured it out after limiting the amount of trees to 1, then 2).

If someone could explain to me what to do to fix this that will be much appreciated.

I have a secondary option of moving the intersect detection into the `switch` statement in the `Blocks` class if necessary, would that fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting p.Intersection in every iteration of the loop.
Don't set it to false in the loop. Set it to false as the default and then change it to true if a collision is detected.

Edit: Also you need to put the player in the outer loop and the blocks in the inner one.

```
     foreach (Player p in main.initializer.playerlist)
     {
        p.intersection = false;

        foreach (Blocks b in main.initializer.blocklist)
        {
            if (p.Hitbox.Intersects(b.box))
                {
                p.intersection = true;
                break;  
                }
        }
}
```